# syntax highlghting in vim

Tags: vim, editors, syntax-highlighting

I have text files which have extensions `*.sc`. So to make syntax highlighting for some of the keywords in that type of text files I created `~/.vim/syntax/sc.cim`. Below is the file content.

```
user $ cd ~/.vim/syntax/
user $ cat sc.vim 
" Syntax highlightor file for files ending in *.sc
syn keyword basicLanguageKeywords interface channel behavior
user $
```

Also I added following line to `~/.vimrc`

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sc set filetype=sc
```

Now I was hoping that when I do `:set syntax=sc` in vim, the syntax highlighting would be in effect for `*.sc` files. But it is not working.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What are your `filetype` settings?

Comment: where ? in `~/.vimrc` ?

Comment: I have just this one line. `filetype on` in it.

Comment: And your `syntax` setting? If `filetype on`  is set, you shouldn't have to do `set syntax=sc`.

Comment: I also have `syntax on`. You mean I dont have to do `:set syntax=sc` if I have `filetype on` right. But it is not working. Does my `sc.vim` look correct ?  Or the `autocmd` line in `~/.vimrc` is wrong ?

Comment: Both of them look right. But have you defined a highlight setting for `basicLanguageKeywords`? Try `:highlight basicLanguageKeywords ctermfg=blue`, and see if your keywords show up in blue.

Comment: Yes the command `:highlight basicLanguageKeywords ctermfg=blue` makes them blue. But how can i fix it permanently ?

Comment: Also, do drop by [vi.se] if you're interested in Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your own syntax group names, like `basicLanguageKeywords`, then you'll have to create highlight settings for them. Stick to commonly used names so that your syntax settings work with most colour schemes. Checkout [`:h group-name`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#group-name):

```
To be able to allow each user to pick his favorite set of colors, there must
be preferred names for highlight groups that are common for many languages.
These are the suggested group names (if syntax highlighting works properly
you can see the actual color, except for "Ignore"):
    *Comment        any comment

    *Constant       any constant
     String         a string constant: "this is a string"
     Character      a character constant: 'c', '\n'
     Number         a number constant: 234, 0xff
     Boolean        a boolean constant: TRUE, false
     Float          a floating point constant: 2.3e10

    *Identifier     any variable name
     Function       function name (also: methods for classes)

    *Statement      any statement
     Conditional    if, then, else, endif, switch, etc.
     Repeat         for, do, while, etc.
     Label          case, default, etc.
     Operator       "sizeof", "+", "*", etc.
     Keyword        any other keyword
     Exception      try, catch, throw
```

In this case, that would be `Keyword`.

Comment: I added line `hi def link basicLanguageKeywords Keyword
` in `~/.vim/syntax/sc.vim` and it is working now.

Comment: @sps you might have just named your group `Keyword` directly: `syn keyword Keyword interface ...`.